# How can I set or retrieve availability entries via the Active Collab API?

Tags: activecollab

Active Collab users can add or edit availability entries to manage their holidays, sick days etc. via the Active Collab browser interface. Unfortunately I didn't find an API method in the API documentation to manage these entries via the API. As we have a stand-alone solution for managing employee absences (www.absence.io) I need a solution to sync the absences with Active Collab.

Is there a (maybe undocumented) way to set availabilities for users via the API?

Best,
Alex

Comment: A more up to date answer posted. If you have any specific questions aside the basic record manipulation, please let me know and I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

at this point in time there is no such API implemented, you can contact support at support@activecollab.com and they can add your vote for the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more up-to-date answer. Availability records for each individual user are available for retrieval by sending GET requests to `/api/v1/availability-records/users/#USER-ID`.

They are added for each user by sending POST request to the same API resource. Following POST fields are required:

- `availability_type_id` - type of availability record. You can get a full list by sending GET request to `/api/v1/availability-types`,
- `message` - Optional message,
- `start_date` - Start of the record, in `YYYY-MM-DD` format,
- `end_date` - End of the record, in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

Individual records are removed by sending DELETE request to `/api/v1/availability-records/2623`.

Availability records for multiple people is retrieved by sending a GET request to `/api/v1/availability-records/all?start_date=YYYY-MM-DD&end_date=YYYY-MM-DD` resource.